# Remove perticular keyword from a file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, duplicates

I have a file which contains

```
"word1"
"word2"
"word3"
```

but i want to remove all " from this file and want

```
word1
word2
word3
```

what should be its command in shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tr:

```
tr -d '"' < file
```

OR sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/"//g' file
```

Comment: hi anubhav, this is working, can you please explain me how this sed command is working?

Comment: sed command searches for `"` and replaces them by empty string. `/g` is for global search and `-i.bak` is for in-line editing.